# Difference between multiple CTE and recusrive CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I am looking at different CTE examples online since I am trying to learn CTE but I a came across two primary ways to write CTEs

1. **Recursive  CTE** which has an anchor and then UNIONs with the child query which uses the results from anchor and previous calls
2. **Multiple CTE** where there are two distinct CTEs defined comma saperated however, the second one ends up referring to the first one which is kind of like the Recursive CTE.

I am referring to an example below:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/08/sql-server-multiple-cte-in-one-select-statement-query/

and wondering how is it different than a Recursive with UNION and a single CTE name?

Comment: The difference is that one is recursive and the other is not? Not sure how to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTEs don't have to be recursive. You can use them instead of sub-queries which is what the first example is doing. You can have one or many CTEs in the place of sub-queries.

The best way to understand CTEs is to create some test data and run the two queries against them to see how the results differ.

Comment: What he said. A CTE is just a derived query with the added bonus that it CAN reference itself (i.e. a recursive cte). I use them all the time in place of derived tables because I like the way my code looks with them. But the main thing is that if you want it to be recursive, it's got to be a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE builds out its anchor set from within the derived CTE expression, usually based on the WHERE, etc. limiting conditions.  The recursion is self-contained, as opposed to having dependencies on other, earlier-defined expressions/sets.

Assuming by multiple CTEs, you mean a set of CTEs in series defined by subsequent SELECT statements, then this is, by comparison, a set of transformations against the anchor sets (and fields) in order of definition.